# Parse shapefile with UTM coordinates without .prj

Tags: javascript, shapefile, utm

I need to convert shapefiles (`.shp`, `.shx` and `.dbf`, but no `.prj`) to geojson. I'm using https://github.com/mbostock/shapefile.

The problem is in shapefiles with UTM coordinates. I need to convert UTM `[easting, northing]` to `[lon, lat]`, but I dont know how to define coordinate system without `.prj` file.

I know this is possible because https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/ can parse my files and define CRS without `.prj`.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible.

I think, https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/ uses random UTM zone, when he can't find `.prj` file